# Create an automatically increasing primary key column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I am following the examples in [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
     did    integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
     name   varchar(40) NOT NULL CHECK (name <> '')
);
```

However, it gives me *ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GENERATED"*. Why is that and how should I fix it?

- `\! psql -V` returns *psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-1.pgdg14.04+1)*
- `SELECT version();` returns *PostgreSQL 9.4.19 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.4.19-1.pgdg14.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit*

---

Edits:

Thanks to @muistooshort, I checked [the 9.4 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html). So I execute:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
     did    integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('serial'),
     name   varchar(40) NOT NULL CHECK (name <> '')
);
```

Nevertheless, it now gives me *ERROR:  relation "serial" does not exist*...

Comment: `psql` is from PostgreSQL 10.5 but what version of PostgreSQL is the server running?

Comment: @muistooshort `SELECT version();` gives me _PostgreSQL 9.4.19 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.4.19-1.pgdg14.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit_. Does it mean that I should read documentation for version 9.4 instead of 10?

Comment: Yes, check the 9.4 docs. AFAIK `IDENTITY` was added in version 10, you'll want to use `serial` with 9.4.

Comment: @muistooshort I just tried that but failed again. Would you mind checking my edits? Should I create relation `serial` just to create `distributors`?

Comment: I need a bit more space than a comment provides so I added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQL standard `IDENTITY` was added in PostgreSQL 10 but your server (which does all the real work) is 9.4. Before 10 you have to use `serial` or `bigserial` types:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
     did    serial not null primary key,
     name   varchar(40) NOT NULL CHECK (name <> '')
);
```

The [`serial` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) will create a sequence to supply values, attach the sequence to the table, and hook up a default value for `did` to get values from the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Just out of curiosity, why doesn't the example provided in the 9.4 docs work then?

Comment: Maybe you're reading the docs wrong. `serial` so it replaces `integer`, `nextval` takes a sequence name as its argument but the `serial` pseudo-type supplies the default value for you.

Comment: I figured it may be that way, but I literally copied and pasted the example in that doc...

Comment: The example is incomplete, sometimes documentation leaves things out to avoid confusing what they're trying to show you.